# Varnish: use match from regex in replacement string

Tags: regex, varnish, varnish-vcl

Heey all, I'm struggling with the following within Varnish

```
if (req.url ~ "/somepath/(.*)/saml/sp/metadata") {
        set req.backend = somebackend_https;
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "/somepath/(.*)/saml/sp/metadata","$1/saml/sp/metadata");
        set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, "^(.*).(.*)", "somehost.nl");
        set req.proto = regsub(req.proto, "^HTTP", "^HTTPS");
        return (lookup);
}
```

How do I get the match from (.*) within the replacement string?
I tried, $1, \1 nothing seems to work. Did I miss something or should I solve this problem in a different way?

I use Varnish 3.

Already thanks in advance!

Comment: \1 should work fine, I think the error is elsewhere

Comment: I dont know what you're trying to do here `set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, "^(.*).(.*)", "somehost.nl");` but you should be very careful with the greedy nature of regexs. That regex will match anything followed by any character followed by anything, that means anything with one character or more.

Comment: Besides, `set req.proto = regsub(req.proto, "^HTTP", "^HTTPS");` is wrong because you don't need to add '^' in the replacement string.

Comment: @Redithion i tried that ahost.nl/somepath/{variable}/saml/sp/metadata will be translated to somehost.nl/{variable}/saml/sp/metadata. For me its important the user shouldnt know in any way that this specific call go to another domain.

Comment: @Redithion this was it, another route was the problem!

Comment: @Redithion its really wrong or just overkill? Maybe I should do this: set req.proto = "HTTPS";

Comment: What is wrong is the ^ at the beginning of the replacement string. Is not wrong to do this for example: `set req.proto = regsub(req.proto, "^HTTP", "HTTPS");`

Answer (score 1):

Redithion is right, its `\1`. another route in the configuration which came earlier was the reason why I couldnt figure this out :)